# All models reset when creating a new one in django

Tags: python, django

My goal is to generate a random joinkey for every new model based on a function that takes the models own primary key as an argument.

The problem is that every time I create a new object the joinkey field resets for every single object in my database, which I do not want, I would only like the joinkey to be added to the new object being created.

This is my model:

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")

    @property
    def joinkey(self):
        return random_int(self.pk)
    @joinkey.setter
    def joinkey(self, value):
        joinkey = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)

    def other_user(self):
        return self.users.exclude(username=user.username)
```

and here is the random_int function just in case:

```
def random_int(primarykey):
    return int(randint(10000, 99999) + 1000000 + primarykey)
```

Comment: You should not use @property, this is used to show properties for a model which is dynamically generated. Therefore, every time you view the model object you will see new joinkey.

Comment: Why you need joinkey?

Comment: I need to automatically generate a joinkey for every project that the user can send to others and then others can join the project by entering the joinkey. I wanted to use the pk of the project itself in the key to make sure that each one is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use signals to add values to a field whenever a new object is created.

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    joinkey = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)


    # Remove all this, from here
    @property
    def joinkey(self):
        return random_int(self.pk)
    @joinkey.setter
    def joinkey(self, value):
    # till here
```

Create a new file in same directory as models.py named 'signals.py'

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# import the random_int method

@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def create_joinkey(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create a joinkey whenever a project object is created."""
    if created: 
        instance.joinkey = random_int(instance.id)
        instance.save()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourapp'

    # Add this to use signals
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Comment: this gives me NameError: name 'self' is not defined